# jQuery with ReactJs SVG 3D Tag Cloud Plugin

Tags: jquery, reactjs

i would like to implement a SVG 3D Tag Cloud Plugin to my React Website. I have watched this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hzpl-zpkyy4&t=209s and would like to achieve the same result at the right hand side of my webpage. I have attached the index.js code, index.scss and script.js code below. Totally new to ReactJs, sorry if I'm not providing enough information or phrasing the question correctly.

index.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Loader from 'react-loaders'
import AnimatedLetters from '../AnimatedLetters'
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import $ from 'jquery';
import './index.scss'

const Skills = () => {
  const [letterClass, setLetterClass] = useState('text-animate')

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLetterClass('text-animate-hover')
    }, 3000)
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var entries = [
        { label : 'AutoCAD'},
        { label : 'CSS'},
        { label : 'C#'},
        { label : 'C++'},
        { label : 'Dart'},
        { label : 'Flutter'},
        { label : 'HTML'},
        { label : 'JavaScript'},
        { label : 'MATLAB'},
        { label : 'Microsoft Office'},
        { label : 'Microsoft Visual Basic'},
        { label : 'MySQL'},
        { label : 'npm'},
        { label : 'Photoshop'},
        { label : 'React'},
        { label : 'SCSS'},
        { label : 'Unity 2D'},
      ];

      var settings = {
        entries : entries,
        width:640,
        height:480,
        raidus:'65%',
        radiusMin:75,
        bgDraw:true,
        bgColor:'#000',
        opacityOver:1.00,
        opacityOut:0.05,
        opacitySpeed:6,
        fov:800,
        speed:2,
        fontFamily:'Courier, Arial, sans-serif',
        fontSize:'30',
        fontColor:'#000',
        fontWeight:'bold',
        fontStyle:'normal',
        fontStretch:'normal',
        fontToUpperCase:true
      };
      $('#tag').svg3DTagCloud(settings);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container skills-page">
        <div className="text-zone">
          <h1>
            <AnimatedLetters
              letterClass={letterClass}
              strArray={['S', 'k', 'i', 'l', 'l', 's']}
              idx={15}
            />
          </h1>
          <h2 class="quote">
          "Jack Of All Trades, Master Of None"
          </h2>
          <p align="LEFT">
          That would be how I would describe myself. Some experience in 
          <span class="tech-tag"> AutoCAD</span>
          , 
          <span class="tech-tag"> CSS</span>
          , 
          <span class="tech-tag"> C#</span>
          , 
          <span class="tech-tag"> C++</span>
          , 
          <span class="tech-tag"> Dart</span>
          , 
          <span class="tech-tag"> Flutter</span>
          , 
          <span class="tech-tag"> HTML</span>
          , 
          <span class="tech-tag"> JavaScript</span>
          , 
          <span class="tech-tag"> MATLAB</span>
          ,
          <span class="tech-tag"> Microsoft Office</span>
          , 
          <span class="tech-tag"> Microsoft Visual Basic</span>
          , 
          <span class="tech-tag"> MySQL</span>
          , 
          <span class="tech-tag"> npm</span>
          , 
          <span class="tech-tag"> Photoshop</span>
          , 
          <span class="tech-tag"> React</span>
          , 
          <span class="tech-tag"> SCSS</span>
          , and 
          <span class="tech-tag"> Unity 2D</span>.
          </p>
          <p>
          I have exposed myself to various software technologies and am always keen to learn new ones. I put special effort into optimizing my code and ensuring the project's objective is delivered.
          </p>
          <p>
          Visit my <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/deandrehaijielim/" target="_blank">LinkedIn</a> profile for more details. Also, you can check out my CV on this link. 
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="tag"></div>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
      <script src="script.js"></script>

      <Loader type="pacman" />
    </>
  )
}

export default Skills
```

index.scss

```
.quote {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 21px;
}

.tech-tag {
    color: #8d8d8d;
  }

a:link {
  color: #8d8d8d;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: gray;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #9899a5;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a:active {
  color: lightyellow;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

div#tag{
  position: absolute;
  right: 25%;
}
```

script.js

```
/*
Copyright (c) 2017 Niklas Knaack
Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
THE SOFTWARE.
*/

!function(){window.SVG3DTagCloud=function(t,e){var i={entries:[],width:480,height:480,radius:"70%",radiusMin:75,bgDraw:!0,bgColor:"#000",opacityOver:1,opacityOut:.05,opacitySpeed:6,fov:800,speed:2,fontFamily:"Arial, sans-serif",fontSize:"15",fontColor:"#fff",fontWeight:"normal",fontStyle:"normal",fontStretch:"normal",fontToUpperCase:!1,tooltipFontFamily:"Arial, sans-serif",tooltipFontSize:"15",tooltipFontColor:"#fff",tooltipFontWeight:"normal",tooltipFontStyle:"normal",tooltipFontStretch:"normal",tooltipFontToUpperCase:!1,tooltipTextAnchor:"left",tooltipDiffX:0,tooltipDiffY:10,animatingSpeed:.01,animatingRadiusLimit:1.3};if(void 0!==e)for(var o in e)e.hasOwnProperty(o)&&i.hasOwnProperty(o)&&(i[o]=e[o]);if(!i.entries.length)return!1;var n,r,a,s,l,u,c,d=[],m=!0,f={x:0,y:0},p={x:0,y:0,z:0},h={x:0,y:0},v={sx:0,cx:0,sy:0,cy:0},y=Math.PI/180,g="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",w=1;function A(){window.cancelAnimFrame(c),window.removeEventListener("resize",M),u&&l.removeChild(u),l&&(t.removeChild(l),l.removeEventListener("mousemove",D),delete l)}function b(){(l=document.createElementNS(g,"svg")).addEventListener("mousemove",D),t.appendChild(l),i.bgDraw&&((u=document.createElementNS(g,"rect")).setAttribute("x",0),u.setAttribute("y",0),u.setAttribute("fill",i.bgColor),l.appendChild(u)),function(){for(var t=!1,e=1,o=i.entries.length+1;e<o;e++){var r=Math.acos(2*e/o-1),a=Math.sqrt(o*Math.PI)*r,s=Math.cos(a)*Math.sin(r),u=Math.sin(a)*Math.sin(r),c=Math.cos(r),m=F(e-1,i.entries[e-1],s,u,c);d.push(m),void 0!==i.entries[e-1].tooltip&&(t=!0)}t&&((n=document.createElementNS(g,"text")).setAttribute("x",0),n.setAttribute("y",0),n.setAttribute("fill",i.tooltipFontColor),n.setAttribute("font-family",i.tooltipFontFamily),n.setAttribute("font-size",i.tooltipFontSize),n.setAttribute("font-weight",i.tooltipFontWeight),n.setAttribute("font-style",i.tooltipFontStyle),n.setAttribute("font-stretch",i.tooltipFontStretch),n.setAttribute("text-anchor",i.tooltipTextAnchor),n.textContent="",l.appendChild(n))}(),x(),C(),window.addEventListener("resize",M)}function x(){var e=window.innerWidth||document.documentElement.clientWidth||document.body.clientWidth,o=window.innerHeight||document.documentElement.clientHeight||document.body.clientHeight,n=e,c=o;i.width.toString().indexOf("%")>0||i.height.toString().indexOf("%")>0?(n=Math.round(t.offsetWidth/100*parseInt(i.width)),c=Math.round(n/100*parseInt(i.height))):(n=parseInt(i.width),c=parseInt(i.height)),e<=n&&(n=e),o<=c&&(c=o),s={x:n/2,y:c/2},h.x=i.speed/s.x,h.y=i.speed/s.y,(a=n>=c?c/100*parseInt(i.radius):n/100*parseInt(i.radius))<1&&(a=1),(r=a/2)<i.radiusMin&&(r=i.radiusMin,a=2*r),l.setAttribute("width",n),l.setAttribute("height",c),i.bgDraw&&(u.setAttribute("width",n),u.setAttribute("height",c)),function(t){for(var e=0,i=d.length;e<i;e++)o=d[e],n=t,void 0,void 0,void 0,void 0,r=o.vectorPosition.x-p.x,a=o.vectorPosition.y-p.y,s=o.vectorPosition.z-p.z,l=Math.sqrt(r*r+a*a+s*s),o.vectorPosition.x/=l,o.vectorPosition.y/=l,o.vectorPosition.z/=l,o.vectorPosition.x*=n,o.vectorPosition.y*=n,o.vectorPosition.z*=n;var o,n,r,a,s,l}(r*w)}function F(t,e,o,n,r){var a={};return void 0!==e.label?(a.element=document.createElementNS(g,"text"),a.element.setAttribute("x",0),a.element.setAttribute("y",0),a.element.setAttribute("fill",i.fontColor),a.element.setAttribute("font-family",i.fontFamily),a.element.setAttribute("font-size",e.fontSize?e.fontSize:i.fontSize),a.element.setAttribute("font-weight",i.fontWeight),a.element.setAttribute("font-style",i.fontStyle),a.element.setAttribute("font-stretch",i.fontStretch),a.element.setAttribute("text-anchor","middle"),a.element.textContent=i.fontToUpperCase?e.label.toUpperCase():e.label):void 0!==e.image&&(a.element=document.createElementNS(g,"image"),a.element.setAttribute("x",0),a.element.setAttribute("y",0),a.element.setAttribute("width",e.width),a.element.setAttribute("height",e.height),a.element.setAttribute("id","image_"+t),a.element.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink","href",e.image),a.diffX=e.width/2,a.diffY=e.height/2),a.link=document.createElementNS(g,"a"),a.link.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink","xlink:href",e.url),a.link.setAttribute("target",e.target),a.link.addEventListener("mouseover",P,!0),a.link.addEventListener("mouseout",z,!0),a.link.appendChild(a.element),void 0!==e.tooltip?(a.tooltip=!0,a.tooltipLabel=i.tooltipFontToUpperCase?e.tooltip.toUpperCase():e.tooltip):a.tooltip=!1,a.index=t,a.mouseOver=!1,a.vectorPosition={x:o,y:n,z:r},a.vector2D={x:0,y:0},l.appendChild(a.link),a}function S(t){for(var e=0,i=d.length;e<i;e++){var o=d[e];if(o.element.getAttribute("x")===t.getAttribute("x")&&o.element.getAttribute("y")===t.getAttribute("y"))return o}}function C(){c=requestAnimFrame(C),function(){var t=h.x*f.x-i.speed,e=i.speed-h.y*f.y,o=t*y,n=e*y;v.sx=Math.sin(o),v.cx=Math.cos(o),v.sy=Math.sin(n),v.cy=Math.cos(n);for(var l=0,u=d.length;l<u;l++){var c=d[l];if(m){var p=c.vectorPosition.x,g=c.vectorPosition.y*v.sy+c.vectorPosition.z*v.cy;c.vectorPosition.x=p*v.cx+g*v.sx,c.vectorPosition.y=c.vectorPosition.y*v.cy+c.vectorPosition.z*-v.sy,c.vectorPosition.z=p*-v.sx+g*v.cx}var A,b=i.fov/(i.fov+c.vectorPosition.z);c.vector2D.x=c.vectorPosition.x*b+s.x,c.vector2D.y=c.vectorPosition.y*b+s.y,c.diffX&&c.diffY&&(c.vector2D.x-=c.diffX,c.vector2D.y-=c.diffY),c.element.setAttribute("x",c.vector2D.x),c.element.setAttribute("y",c.vector2D.y),m?(A=(r-c.vectorPosition.z)/a)<i.opacityOut&&(A=i.opacityOut):(A=parseFloat(c.element.getAttribute("opacity")),c.mouseOver?A+=(i.opacityOver-A)/i.opacitySpeed:A+=(i.opacityOut-A)/i.opacitySpeed),c.element.setAttribute("opacity",A*(1-(w-1)/(i.animatingRadiusLimit-1)))}d=d.sort(function(t,e){return e.vectorPosition.z-t.vectorPosition.z})}()}function P(t){m=!1;var e,o=S(t.target);!function(t){for(var e=0,i=d.length;e<i;e++){var o=d[e];o.index===t.index?o.mouseOver=!0:o.mouseOver=!1}}(o),o.tooltip&&(e=o).tooltip&&(n.setAttribute("x",e.vector2D.x-i.tooltipDiffX),n.setAttribute("y",e.vector2D.y-i.tooltipDiffY),n.textContent=i.tooltipFontToUpperCase?e.tooltipLabel.toUpperCase():e.tooltipLabel,n.setAttribute("opacity",1))}function z(t){m=!0;var e=S(t.target);e.tooltip&&n.setAttribute("opacity",0)}function D(t){var e,i;e=t,i=l.getBoundingClientRect(),f={x:e.clientX-i.left,y:e.clientY-i.top}}function M(t){x()}function T(t){w=Math.min(Math.max(t,1),i.animatingRadiusLimit),x()}window.requestAnimFrame=window.requestAnimationFrame||window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame||window.mozRequestAnimationFrame||function(t){return window.setTimeout(t,1e3/60)},window.cancelAnimFrame=window.requestAnimationFrame?window.cancelAnimationFrame:window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame?window.webkitCancelAnimationFrame:window.mozRequestAnimationFrame?window.mozCancelAnimationFrame:window.clearTimeout;var E=!1,O=!1,L=!1;function k(){(L=w<i.animatingRadiusLimit)?(T(w+i.animatingSpeed),requestAnimFrame(k)):"function"==typeof E&&(E(),E=!1)}function q(){(L=w>1)?(T(w-i.animatingSpeed),requestAnimFrame(q)):"function"==typeof O&&(O(),O=!1)}b(),this.destroy=A,this.animOut=function(t){L||(w=1,E=t,k())},this.animIn=function(t){L||(w=i.animatingRadiusLimit,O=t,q())},this.setEntries=function(t){A(),i.entries=t,b()}}}(),"undefined"!=typeof jQuery&&function(t){t.fn.svg3DTagCloud=function(e){var i=arguments;return this.each(function(){if(t.data(this,"plugin_SVG3DTagCloud")){var o=t.data(this,"plugin_SVG3DTagCloud");o[e]?o[e].apply(this,Array.prototype.slice.call(i,1)):t.error("Method "+e+" does not exist on jQuery.svg3DTagCloud")}else t.data(this,"plugin_SVG3DTagCloud",new SVG3DTagCloud(this,e))})}}(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import TagCloud from 'TagCloud'

const Tags = [
'JavaScript',
'CSS',
'HTML',
'Vscode',
'XD',
'React',
'Python',
'Linux',
'git',
'Flutter',
'Dart',
'Firebase',
'SASS',
'JSON',
'Figma',
]

function App() {
const IsTagCloudLoaded = useRef(false)

useEffect(() => {
    if (IsTagCloudLoaded.current) return

    TagCloud('.content', Tags, {
        radius: 250,
        maxSpeed: 'fast',
        initSpeed: 'fast',
        direction: 135,
        keep: true,
    })

    IsTagCloudLoaded.current = true
}, [])

return (
    <div className='About' id='About'>
        <div className='left'>
            <div className='heading'>
                <h1>ABOUT</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className='right'>
            <div className='content' />
        </div>
    </div>
)
}

export default App
```

you can also try this....

```
import { TagCloud } from 'react-tagcloud'

const data = [
 { value: 'JavaScript', count: 38 },
 { value: 'React', count: 30 },
 { value: 'Nodejs', count: 28 },
 { value: 'Express.js', count: 25 },
 { value: 'HTML5', count: 33 },
 { value: 'MongoDB', count: 18 },
 { value: 'CSS3', count: 20 },
]

const SimpleCloud = () => (
 <TagCloud
 minSize={12}
 maxSize={35}
 tags={data}
 onClick={tag => alert(`'${tag.value}' was selected!`)}/>
)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.